# Restricting simultaneous inserts that fulfills condition on asynchronous connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asynchronous, transactions

I know that you usually use transactions to ensure concurrency issues. I am not an expert in database logic, but I haven't found anything that explains how to restrict inserts, based on a condition.

In my case, I have an internal rule, that a user can't time punch on more than one job. If the user requesting to punch time is already punching the clock, I end the first one.

However, if the client spams the server, some of them cannot find prior time punches and inserts a new record, blissfully unaware that another process is also doing the same thing.

The table basically looks like this:

### tblTimesheetPunch

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ FK_UserID ║ StartDatetime ║ StopDatetime ║ FK_JobID ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════╝
```

And my check goes:

```
public async Task<long> StartPunchingTimeOnJob(long jobId)
{
    var currentTimesheets = await DbContext.TimesheetPunch.Where(tsp =>
                tsp.User == Session.User
                && tsp.StartDateTime != null
                && tsp.StopDateTime == null)
                .ToListAsync();
    if(currentTimesheets.Count >= 2)
    {
        //Fix duplicates
    }
    else if(currentTimesheets.Count = 1)
    {
        //End the current one
    }
    //Insert the requested one and return its ID
    return newTimesheetPunch.ID;
}
```

I don't want to lock the entire table from inserts during the transaction. I basically just want to lock rows from being inserted with the current transaction's `FK_UserID` value.

Is there an efficient standardized way to do this that I have missed? Or should I perhaps try to cache incoming client insert requests as tasks, and return the ID of the first inserted to all of them? I don't want to rely solely on the client restricting their simultaneous calls, as there are multiple clients and I am not the developer of any of them.

Comment: I would look into MSMQ, inserting records there async and then picking them up sync. Minimal delay

Comment: Just declare unique index, so that it's not possible to insert two rows with the same user id and empty stop time. Then at least your database will always be in consistent state.